# is it grammatically correct to say "You lose"?

Tags: grammar

Why in the game **Street Fighter II**, when you lose the fight, is it said:

> "You lose"

Isn't it grammatically wrong?
It is past, therefore "I lost the fight"
Shouldn't the correct is: "You lost"?

Comment: Why would it be wrong?

Comment: isn't the correct way: "you lost"?

Comment: is it because the "context" is in the present?

Comment: It's not exactly wrong, but yes, "you lost" or "you have lost" would be more typical in normal speech.  I wonder if it might be to sound more 'punchy' because it's a video game, or even because it was written in Japanese and translated?

Comment: As is so often the case, the choice of tense, the speaker can choose different possibilities, depending on how they wish to present the events temporally. _You lose_ is treating the game as a present, continuing event, in which the thing that is happening right now is that you are losing. _You have lost_ treats the losing as something that is in the past, but has present relevance: you are in a state of having lost. In my (British) dialect, I would not say _you lost_ in this context.

Comment: I toss a coin, unfairly. Heads I win, tails you lose.

Comment: "You lose!" is more of an exclamation, with an air of triumph about it. It's commonly used, which obviates any question of grammaticality.